# How to avoid accidentally overloading a super class key attribute or method in python?

Tags: python

How can one prevent accidentally overloading a super class method's key attribute or method? For example, I defined a class that subclasses from threading.Thread and declared 2 datetime attributes called start and end.  The start overloaded the Thread.start() method.  That took me a while to discover.
code example:

```
class b(threading.Thread)
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        start = None
        end = None
    def run(self):
        print('thread started')
```

The declaration start overloaded threading.Thread.start() and
so the start() call for the thread throws an exception sine start is None

Is there a python coding style that avoids this type of error (accidentally
overloading a base class's attribute or method)?
I am new to python and can see myself making this type of mistake again.

Comment: Using an IDE such as pycharm could have warned you about this

Comment: This code does nothing of the sort. start and end are local variables and don't affect anything outside that method.

Comment: I think what @DanielRoseman is grumping about is that your example should be `self.start = None` and `self.end = None`.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to write `self.start` there and not just `start`. You could have made the same mistake in any other dynamic language, you could of course follow a simple pattern and prefix you class attributes with underscore but ultimately you should always check your parent classes to avoid overriding names.